# How do I place 'select all' at the top of a select being populated by a SQL table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I have a `asp:dropdownlist` that is being populated by a `sqldatasource`.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsPharmacy" 
DataTextField="departmentName" DataValueField="departmentName"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

How do I set the first Selection to something like "Select One" without dropping the table and recreating it and adding that as the first value?

Comment: can you manually add a list item to your control `<asp:ListItem>Select One</asp:ListItem>` or does your datasource overwrite everything in the list?

Comment: @Kelix it overwrites everything

Answer (score 2):

Set `AppendDataBoundItems="true"` in your DropDownList after `AutoPostBack="True"` and add a static item inside the DropDownList tag `<asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="" Selected="True"  />`

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDepartment" runat="server" DataSourceID="sdsPharmacy" 
DataTextField="departmentName" DataValueField="departmentName"
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlDepartment_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" 
SelectedValue=<%#Bind("departmentName")%>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

In the departureName you will give the value of departmentName you want to be selected. I suppose that the value you want to be selected is in the dataset of your datasource. Otherwise the correct answer is the answer of Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have to drop and re-create the table to add a row? Are you depending on the "natural" order of the table, populating your drop down with a SELECT with no ORDER BY? A table is an unordered set of rows *by definition*, so if you're currently relying on this natural order, this can change with a plan change, service pack, index change, statistics change, data change, etc. etc. Stop relying on it and add an actual sort column if you want a predictable, deterministic sort in your output.